# How can data be synchronized between processes in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm wondering something perhaps extremely stupid, but I can't seem to find an answer (which is not a good sign, usually).
Assuming we have a SQL server (MySQL, PostgreSQL, this question even applies to Sqlite3 though there's no server) and several clients connected to it. I've seen countless times queries that might be hard to sync in my opinion.
So let's assume we have a table (usage statistics, say) with a row per day.

```
statistic (
    day,
    num_requests
)
```

(I avoid mentioning data types, since it's not the point, but the number of requests should be a number of some sort.)

So when a new web request is sent, the web server will ask this table's current statistic and increase the number of requests.  No biggie right?

```py
number = cursor.execute("""
        SELECT num_requests FROM statistic
        WHERE ...
""")
number += 1
cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE statistic SET num_requests=?
        WHERE ...
""", (number, ))
```

But what does happen if two requests are handled somewhat simultaneously, perhaps on several clients?  Different processes?  They each ask for today's current statistic (just a read operation, non-blocking), they get the number of requests from this row (this step doesn't involve the server) and then they increment it by 1.  At this point, if both requests are running somewhat simultaneously, they have both incremented the same number once and they send an `UPDATE` requests with their number.

In the end, the number of requests for today's statistic has increased by one, although they were two requests.  I know there are mechanisms to ensure proper data synchronization, but I fail to see how it could address the situation in this case.  Read usually is non-blocking as far as I know.  Write can be blocking, but since read for the other process has happened before, the second write operation will not be acceptable.  And I don't see any way to express that logically.

In other words, this seems like the point where we would lock the row in most programming languages, and say "from that point onward, you can neither read it or write it, I'm working on it".  The first request will execute its read (lock), increment and write, and then will unlock.  The second request will have to wait patiently for the lock to be released.  I don't see that mechanism in SQL.  Is that transparent and not even necessary?  And if so, how does it work?  Or have we lived our entire life with problems like it?

Thanks!

Comment: Most SQL implementations support both explicit locking and try to do it automatically to implement [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation) of transactions.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute("""
    UPDATE statistic SET num_requests=num_requests+1
    WHERE ...
""", (number, ))
```

Comment: I see. Does it mean, then, that ORMs, whose task is to get an object from the database and manage updates seamlessly, are at a disadvantage here? I never saw an ORM perform this operation, but that doesn't mean it doesn't.